# Convert SQL Server IIF function to Redshift

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-redshift

I have sql server script, that I need to convert to Redshift

Here is part of code that I have problem with

```
IIF(smf.channelid IS NULL, 0, 1) AS IsFeatureKey,
IIF(codeLabel.CslId > 0, 1, 0) AS IsCslCode,
IIF(codeLabel.LearnId > 0, 1, 0) AS IsLearnCode,
IIF(codeLabel.PMId > 0, 1, 0) AS IsPMCode,
IIF(codeLabel.UpSell > 0, 1, 0) AS IsUpSell
```

How I can convert it to Redshift correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is just syntactic sugar for `CASE` expression (this behavior is mentioned in the documentation). Your code is identical to:

```
CASE WHEN smf.channelid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsFeatureKey,
CASE WHEN codeLabel.CslId > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsCslCode,
CASE WHEN codeLabel.LearnId > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsLearnCode,
CASE WHEN codeLabel.PMId > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsPMCode,
CASE WHEN codeLabel.UpSell > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsUpSell
```